# How to make a map of a country (Maldives) in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I am trying to obtain a map of the Maldives, similar to the one seen in the image. However, I am struggling with the xlim and ylim. Any suggestions?

```
library(cowplot)
library(googleway)
library(ggplot2) 
library(ggrepel) 
library(ggspatial) 
library(libwgeom)
library(sf) 
library(rnaturalearth) 
library(rnaturalearthdata)

theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(data = world) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-102.15, -74.12), ylim = c(7.65, 33.97), expand = FALSE)
```

[image: sample map]

Answer (score 1):

The Maldives don't make for a great map in this format, since they are so individually small and spread out. In fact, if you use the medium resolution data from `rnaturalearth` that you are currently using, you will only see one or two of the hundreds of islands, and they will just appear as little blobs.

Instead, you can get a higher resolution map like this:

```r
maldives <- ne_countries("large", country = "Maldives", returnclass = "sf")

theme_set(theme_bw())

ggplot(data = maldives) + 
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(70, 76))
```

[image]

You can show them in relation to the nearby countries of India and Sri Lanka if you just want to see their overall shape, extent and location:

```r
maldives <- ne_countries("large", 
                         country = c("Maldives", "India", "Sri Lanka"), 
                         returnclass = "sf")

theme_set(theme_bw())

ggplot(data = maldives) + 
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(72, 82), ylim = c(-1, 15))
```

[image]

Another option is to colour the map to allow the islands to "pop"

```r
ggplot(data = maldives) + 
  geom_sf(fill = "#55790A", color = "#90FF20") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(72, 82), ylim = c(-1, 15)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#342255"),
        panel.grid = element_line(color = "#4f4f6f"))
```

[image]

Or stick to your original format  but zoom in to near the capital:

```r
ggplot(data = maldives) + 
  geom_sf() +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(72.5, 73.5), ylim = c(6, 7.2))
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome thanks! is it possible to your script you wrote before : maldives <- ne_countries("large", country = "Maldives", returnclass = "sf")

Comment: @AimeeNicholson-Jack I just loaded all the same libraries as you (except I have also installed `rnaturalearthhires` which is needed for the high res maps.